# Почему в автозагрузку добавляется инжектируемая программа,а не ту которую указал?

Tags: c++

Почему в автозагрузку добавляется инжектируемая программа,а не ту которую указал?

Почему в программа,которая должна быть по пути `Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run` находиться в `Software\\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
HKEY hKey;
    char szPath[0x100];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, szPath, sizeof(szPath));
    RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
        "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",
        NULL,
        "C:\\test.exe",
        REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,
        KEY_SET_VALUE,
        NULL,
        &hKey,
        NULL);
if (hKey)
{
    RegSetValueEx(hKey, "Test", NULL, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)szPath, strlen(szPath));
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вы записали путь к этому приложению `szPath`. `Wow6432Node` это нода виртуализации реестра для 32-битных приложений.

Comment: Хорошо,а что с первым вопросом?

Comment: @DenisFrolov Ответ на первый вопрос содержится в первом предложении моего ответа

Comment: вас непонял,подробнее можно?

Comment: @DenisFrolov Ну куда ж подробнее? Вы записали в реестр путь к этому приложению, а не `"C:\\test.exe",`

Comment: А решение есть?

Comment: @DenisFrolov Конечно, пишите `"C:\\test.exe"`...

Comment: Куда именно это писать? Мой пример не работает...

Comment: @DenisFrolov Ваш пример работает, но вы зачем-то пишите в нем путь к этому приложению вместо `"C:\\test.exe"`

Comment: Ну я пишу это,а в реестре другое                                                               
        NULL,
        "C:\\test.exe",
        REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,

Comment: :) это беда... Автор, код `GetModuleFileName` записывает в `szPath` путь к исполняемому вами файлу, а не ваш путь. В `RegCreateKeyEx` ваш путь совершенно не к месту, там должен быть null, или путь к модулю, читайте https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regcreatekeyexa

Comment: @DenisFrolov В реестр вы пишите `RegSetValueEx(hKey, "Test", NULL, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)szPath, strlen(szPath));`, `RegCreateKeyEx` это создание ключа, причем параметр `"C:\\test.exe"` передается в качестве названия класса, то бишь `"C:\\test.exe"` не нужен в этом вызове от слова совсем, он нужен в `RegSetValueEx`

Comment: всё равно ничего не понял,понял только,что 'szPath' - переменная,но как её заменить не понял.

Comment: Вам надо исполнить `memcpy(szPath, &"c:\test\.exe", sizeof("c:\test\.exe"));` после вызова `RegCreateKeyEx`  и все у вас получиться :)

Comment: @DenisFrolov `auto const & sz_path{"c:\test\.exe"}; RegSetValueEx(hKey, "Test", NULL, REG_SZ, reinterpret_cast<BYTE const *>(static_cast<char const *>(sz_path)), sizeof(sz_path));`

Answer (score 1):

```
HKEY hKey;
char szPath[0x100];
RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run",
    NULL,
    "",
    REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,
    KEY_SET_VALUE,
    NULL,
    &hKey,
    NULL);
memcpy(szPath, &"С:\\test.exe", sizeof("С:\\test.exe"));
if (hKey)
{
    RegSetValueEx(hKey, "Test", NULL, REG_SZ, (LPBYTE)szPath, strlen(szPath));
    RegCloseKey(hKey);
}
```

Comment: Правильный ответ дал вам @VTT, исходя из этого, отметьте его ответ как правильный, мистер плагиатор :)

Comment: @NewView вы мне дали правильный ответ...

Comment: Нет, правильный ответ дал VTT, я просто попробовал изложить тоже самое в более простой форме :) и ответа я не давал, это только рекомендации :)

Comment: @NewView ясно...

Comment: Вот так будет правильней, спасибо за понимание

Comment: А с этим вариантом будет проблема из-за записи на один символ меньше. Значения с типом `REG_SZ` должны содержать оканчивающуюся нулем строку. Ну и копирование в массив `szPath` является излишнимю

Comment: @VTT, Ну это очевидно, но автору пока не до этого, хотя ключь пишется по размеру, и если вместо strlen использовать константный sizeof то ничего страшного не случиться. Или `char szPath[0x100]={0};`, или ваш С++ код.

Comment: @NewView Так а страшное случается из-за использования `strlen` вместо `sizeof` - записывается на один байт меньше

Comment: Ну не знаю,у меня всё нормально... https://pp.userapi.com/c846416/v846416478/1772e7/TC_FNTeRqIk.jpg